# session variables not being set

Tags: php, session

I am having a problem with my session variables not being set. The files are created, but they are blank.

My session files are set up to go in a directory above the public www. root. The login form is in the root dir. The admin pages are in a subdir. I have two config files set up to reflect the different paths for each section. Session() start is called in both and on every page. Yet as soon as I log in and am redirected to the admin area, vardump reflects an empty session array.

from the admin config file:

```
define("MYSQLADMIN", "../../etc/mysqli.inc.php");
define("MY_SESSION_NAME", "endangeredspecies");
ini_set("session.save_path","../../mySessionFolder");
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime','0');
//ini_set('session.cookie_secure','1');
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly','1');
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies','1');
ini_set("session.entropy_file","/dev/urandom");
session_name(MY_SESSION_NAME);
session_start();
```

The code that sets the session variables is in an include file on the login page (which is in the doc root) (the include file is above it). A sample of the session setting code:

```
$_SESSION["member_id"] = $member["user_id"]; //unique
$_SESSION["email"] = $member["user_email"];
```

the block is executing as the redirect is working.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Edit: After removing the redirect the error messages seemed to suggest it was a path problem. The guys at my webhosting suggested I used an absolute path, and that seemed to work. But I might change where I call session_start() if its better practice too. Appreciate the help

Thanks!

Comment: write session_start(); at the top of your page

Answer (score 1):

You have to include `session_start()` at the top of the page and 
then do

```
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly','1');
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies','1');
ini_set("session.entropy_file","/dev/urandom");
session_name(MY_SESSION_NAME);
```

**NOTE** Also check your `php.ini` settings also whether you have allowed session variables to get stored in your server

Answer (score 0):

You should have to start session first and the assign name...

```
   //ini_set('session.cookie_secure','1');
   ini_set('session.cookie_httponly','1');
   ini_set('session.use_only_cookies','1');
   ini_set("session.entropy_file","/dev/urandom");

  // **Change here**
   session_start();
   session_name(MY_SESSION_NAME);
```